# Strange SaveChanges behavior in Entity Framework and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, unique-constraint, savechanges

I have some code, you can check project [github](https://github.com/hamaronooo/InfTeh_test), error contains in `UploadContoller` method `GetExtensionId`.

Database diagram:

[image]

Code (in this controller I sending files to upload):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase[] files, int? folderid, string description)
    {
        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
                string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)?.Remove(0, 1);
                
                int? extensionid = GetExtensionId(fileExt);
                
                if (CheckFileExist(fileName, fileExt, folderid))
                {
                    fileName = fileName + $" ({DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss")})";
                }

                File dbFile = new File();
                dbFile.folderid = folderid;
                dbFile.displayname = fileName;
                dbFile.file_extensionid = extensionid;
                dbFile.file_content = GetFileBytes(file);
                dbFile.description = description;

                db.Files.Add(dbFile);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Partial_UnknownErrorToast", "Toast");
    }
```

I want to create Extension in database if it not exist yet. And I do it with `GetExtensionId`:

```
    private static object locker = new object();
    private int? GetExtensionId(string name)
    {
        int? result = null;
        lock (locker)
        {
            var extItem = db.FileExtensions.FirstOrDefault(m => m.displayname == name);

            if (extItem != null) return extItem.file_extensionid;

            var fileExtension = new FileExtension()
            {
                displayname = name
            };
            db.FileExtensions.Add(fileExtension);
            db.SaveChanges();
            result = fileExtension.file_extensionid;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

In the SQL Server database I have unique constraint on displayname column of FileExtension.

**Problem** starts only if I uploading few files with the same extension and this extension not exist in database yet.

If I remove `lock`, in `GetExtensionId` will be `Exception` about unique constraint.

Maybe, for some reason, next iteration of `foreach` cycle calls `GetExtensionId` without waiting? I don't know.
But only if I set `lock` my code works fine.

If you know why it happens please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a simple concurrency race condition. Imagine two requests come in at once; they both check the `FirstOrDefault`, which correctly says "nope" for both. Then they both try and insert; one wins, one fails because the DB has changed. While EF manages transactions around `SaveChanges`, that transaction doesn't start from when you query the data initially

The `lock` appears to work, by preventing them getting into the looking code at the same time, but this is not a reliable solution for this in general, as it only works inside a single process, let alone node.

So: a few option here:

- your code could detect the foreign key violation exception and recheck from the start (FirstOrDefault etc), which keeps things simple in the success case (which is going to be the majority of the time) and not horribly expensive in the failure case (just an exception and an extra DB hit) - pragmatic enough
- you could move the "select if exists, insert if it doesn't" into a single operation inside the database *inside a transaction* (ideally serializable isolation level, and/or using the `UPDLOCK` hint) - this requires writing TSQL yourself, rather than relying on EF, but minimises round trips and avoids writing "detect failure and compensate" code
- you could perform the selects and possible inserts *inside a transaction via EF* - complicated and messy, frankly: don't do this (and it would again need to be serializable isolation level, but now the serializable transaction spans multiple round trips, which can start to impact locking, if at scale)

Comment: However, why do the different iterations of the loop call the method until the first iteration has finished? Because, apparently, this is exactly what is happening ...